# Como se usa el metodo synchronized de forma correcta

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo que realizar un proyecto en el que se sincronicen 10 hilos, en el cual son hay 5 hilos de `Ping` y 5 hilos de `Pong`. Uno debe de imprimir `"Ping"`, y otro `"Pong"` y lo deben de imprimir alternadamente por Ejemplo:

```
Ping(2)       
Pong(6)   
Ping(4)   
Pong(5)
```

En el cual el numero del paréntesis indica de cual hilo proviene, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me imprime

```
Ping(2)  
Ping(4)  
Ping(3)  
Ping(1)  
Ping(5)  
   Pong(6)  
   Pong(7)  
   Pong(5)  
   Pong(9)  
   Pong(10)
```

Mi código:

```
package Hilos;
public class Hilos {
    public void iniciar() {
        Ping x1= new Ping("ping", 1);
        Thread th1= new Thread(x1);

        Ping x2= new Ping("ping",2);
        Thread th2= new Thread(x2);

        Ping x3= new Ping("ping",3);
        Thread th3= new Thread(x3);

        Ping x4= new Ping("ping",4);
        Thread th4= new Thread(x4);

        Ping x5= new Ping("ping",5);
        Thread th5= new Thread(x5);

        Ping x6= new Ping("pong",6);
        Thread th6= new Thread(x6);

        Ping x7= new Ping("pong",7);
        Thread th7= new Thread(x7);

        Ping x8= new Ping("pong",8);
        Thread th8= new Thread(x8);

        Ping x9= new Ping("pong",9);
        Thread th9= new Thread(x9);

        Ping x10= new Ping("pong",10);
        Thread th10= new Thread(x10);

        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();
        th4.start();
        th5.start();
        th6.start();
        th7.start();
        th8.start();
        th9.start();
        th10.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hilos h = new Hilos();
        h.iniciar();
    }
}

class Ping implements Runnable {
    static boolean bandera = true;
    String c;
    int cual;

    public Ping(String c, int cual) {
        this.c = c;
        this.cual = cual;
    }

    public synchronized void Imprimir(){
        if(c=="ping"&&bandera==true){
            System.out.println(c+cual);
            bandera=false;
        }
        if(c.equals("pong")&&bandera==false){
            System.out.println("\t"+c+cual);
            bandera=true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Imprimir();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que he visto que pasa es que el Metodo `Imprimir`, que supuestamente está sincronizada, en realidad no lo esta ya que los 10 hilos entran al mismo tiempo y con eso sucede que se impriman los 5 *ping* consecutivos y luego los 5 *pong*, así sucesivamente. Estuve probando varias alternativas pero ninguna me funciono.

Gracias por su tiempo y espero me puedan ayudar a resolver mi problema. :)
**Feliz dia a todos!.**

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy bien elaborada.. te pediria que vieras el [tour] solo como referencia para saber como funciona el sitio. y si quieres mira [ask]. Bienvenido! (nota al margen, evita los saludos ;) )

Comment: *La clase Imprimir que supuestamente está sincronizada[...]* No veo una clase *Imprimir*, ¿te refieres al método *imprimir1*? Si es así, puedes corregir la pregunta, si no deberías añadir las partes relevante de la clase (tienes el botón *editar* para modificar la pregunta).

Comment: Amm la verdad es que no tengo mucho conocimiento de progrmacion pero, lo que intento sincronizar es el metodo imprimir y ese es todo el codigo que tengo, me gustaria saber en eh fallado y que tengo mal o si todo esta mal. Gracias por su tiempo :#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La sincronización en *java* funciona a nivel de objeto. Lo que un método *sincronizado* te garantiza es que no habrá dos hilos ejecutando un mismo método de un mismo objeto a la vez. Si hay varios hilos intentando ejecutar el mismo método del mismo objeto a la misma vez, uno logrará su ejecución y los otros deberán esperar a que este concluya para obtener su turno.

El problema que estamos teniendo, en tu caso, es que tenemos 10 objetos diferentes, y por tanto, cada objeto está tratando de sincronizarse únicamente consigo mismo, con lo cual no hay ninguna sincronización en efecto.

Lo que debemos hacer es lograr que esa sincronización funcione de manera global.

Una manera de hacerlo, es declarar tu método `Imprimir` también estático. Al ser estático, en realidad todos los hilos competirán por ese único método a nivel de clase, con lo cual se ven obligados a sincronizarse. En cada llamada, deberás pasarle por parámetro los datos del hilo que lo llama.

```
public static synchronized void imprimir(String c, int cual) {
    if(c == "ping" && bandera){
        System.out.println(c+cual);
        bandera=false;
    }
    if(c.equals("pong")&&!bandera){
        System.out.println("\t"+c+cual);
        bandera=true;
    }
}
```

Hecho esto, sin más cambios, debieras ver el resultado correcto.

He hecho otro par de cambios al código:

1. El nombre del método inicia con minúscula. La convención más general es que solo los nombres de clases inician con mayúscula.
2. He cambiado la manera de *evaluar* las variables booleanas dentro del `if`. `bandera` ya es booleana. No me gusta ver algo como `bandera == true`, que devolverá `true` solo si `bandera` es `true`. Es decir, podemos abreviarlo solamente como `bandera`. Igual `bandera == false` puede abreviarse simplemente como `!bandera`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tiempo y ayuda, entendi el problema que yo entendia que solo existia un metodo Imprimir cuando en realidad existen 10 y muchas gracias por tus ultimos dos comentarios que hiciste sobre el codigo

Comment: Es un gusto, @Alfredo. Te invito a [votar y aceptar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) sobre las respuestas recibidas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

```
public synchronized void Imprimir(){
    if(c=="ping"&&bandera==true){
        System.out.println(c+cual);
        bandera=false;
    }
    if(c.equals("pong")&&bandera==false){
        System.out.println("\t"+c+cual);
        bandera=true;
    }
}
```

Cuando usas *synchronized*, estás usando un objeto que funciona de semáforo. Lo que te garantiza *synchronized* es que no habrá dos hilos distintos dentro del bloque *synchronized* **controlado por el mismo semáforo**.

Es decir:

```
synchronized (objetoA) {
  // Sección crítica A
}

synchronized (objetoB) {
  // Sección crítica B
}
```

Si *objetoA* es el mismo objeto que *objetoB*, solo un hilo puede estar dentro de "Sección crítica A" o "Sección crítica B". Pero si son objetos distintos, entonces un hilo puede estar en "Sección crítica A" y otro estar en "Sección crítica B".

Cuando defines un método de instancia como *synchronized*

```
public synchronized void metodo() {
   ...
}
```

Es equivalente a

```
public void metodo() {
  synchronized (this) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Aquí, cada hilo actúa como semáforo en su llamada a *Imprimir*, con lo cual no se bloquean entre ellos; el *thread1* usará *thread1* como semáforo, verá que nadie lo bloquea (porque los otros hilos también se usan a sí mismos como semáforos) y entrará sin problemas.

La solución es tener un objeto común que se use como semáforo; p.ej:

```
private static Object semaforo = new Object();

public void Imprimir() {
  synchronized (semaforo) {
     // Tu código aquí
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ahora entiendo lo que pasaba y con tu ayuda pude solucionarlo y ya funciono y ademas logre entender como es que realmente funciona synchronizedo por lo menos un poco mas

Answer (score 2):

El método sincronizado que usas para imprimir solo sincroniza para las mismas instancias de Ping, pero tú estás creando varias instancias, de hecho 10.

Si quieres sincronizar todas las instancias de Ping necesitas una sincronización para cualquier instancia:

```
class Ping implements Runnable {

    private static final Object semaforo = new Object();

    public void Imprimir(){
        synchronized(semaforo) { //aquí limitas a solo un Ping a la vez

            if(c=="ping"&&bandera==true){
                System.out.println(c+cual);
                bandera=false;
            }
           if(c.equals("pong")&&bandera==false){
               System.out.println("\t"+c+cual);
                bandera=true;
           }
       }
    }
```